# YouTube "Premium" Channels

Tags: youtube

I was watching [Harley Davidson´s](http://www.youtube.com/harleydavidson) YouTube Channel

And was wondering how were they able to do that flash slideshow at the beginning?

Is this because of a partnership like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/t/partnerships_faq)?

Is it the same as this [Nasa´s Navigation menu](http://www.youtube.com/user/nasatelevision)? or is it "easier" to do?

PS: I couldn´t really find how to do this because I don´t know (the names of) what I´m looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is all the information needed:

http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-brand-channels/

And here is how to contact youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/user/advertise

It is actually a quite hard "selection" process.

Good luck!!